# X-scale does not update (sometimes) on signal change in a Vega chart

Tags: bar-chart, signals, interactive, vega

This is [a somewhat simplified version of a chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-CHyb3VTAMOpcnl8gVQ6pQE26fQQXQZbTi8SSpHomVwOWwpUSEMN7bQlttkCVMmlGtWGyYLt2miTZQzeKQv0BoMLxSN7TL1t2dfaxRb0YmPdyA9TY8QjlFqQlonoP0jriPIzg0ES7YgZ2pb1EBcAgXAsg5uBwqKKCZCpDIEpSugsDTlWbB9CAv7-r8lTBlArzwTBMhAvajr1AA5OR0BUYx2gANS6BWVZusW-IwegSyYSAdEOr8jEjDu2jEGwnQMD8N49iaiFDto7FceWjK8cRfr0SgeKkfU24UpmnT1FguD4EQtCTNQdCMDMCKKJU2rwZglCVAgBBIEkAgHAcOw+QIcCuAALEgUA7FATAAGxhWFcA7AAnO4UBwAIriyAAHFAqXJQcrhIKEBBofYBBwLF9oCIGAhhQI2XJfIADMKUJbFOyHLIyXJVFZipTsTCyENUVwM1BAmR5UAQMQnwQsgSLpFkZEzXYITej0cgyjQpCFLy6D0SJi57fUh3EWipSghAZjzWg+IgJk2TGfGjoGiA-Q4JCgEDPBoFCtoAD8OZlNoqDjOJQoABR7IcUjaAFACU2gADzgy2CCUMdiG6fxXYHdtu00Ao8xeulxkvnYl3iNdt2GQ9y3PZ0r12B9X0uujlDyG8u2qQAhAAvGcDCdOZ-GPYKKGivKIB5DK+1bdz2zY7R5KYDioAYli5lCZLqvETImuvMS3LiAA+lzO1K7yMQhlL7h2FLBw-n+9NPegSBkP8fAMTI-yAjg1Z3aJqv2y7hvayAWmVoHLR+oqIYPoMfqy50sgquIwudH6SAhpNifO0tbsgMIbARB7XsUD7fwAkCgd4sHdD23HeBBwsCDmjLROp7nL759nPc7on2SKEKUsF67vzQr2dh+7Xbr13bHdiCPfIp-tGu+Fr9RRzpv6d3L5OD4C2oggPdCJ6HMu98fmBO4W98G5R3QqkZ6B9KxyztAz6B6FBBTob8Rwzg2TBFCOESIaB3CUHcAIAox99qlBpHaNgyAIh8nDsSFCawACONIwRwEhpgE25sCZW0oFLOGRCIgkMVntSg0IR6UOIRbHmsh6HxBwAjc6Ls8b0g-iJcW9Q3jiH1HYNCkRfg+D8NLWQKCagaFAPpU6pDlDExkGvQ+58b5OzRCkAEaBEHlH5O8EoZRcaCTXHJfhx1byrkEegBsZdzLINQRoOk9gahqAgQbGAKgcDNFjAeEImA8LWy2lAYRys1ygnSiLbGfpxEYSDidLk8kRJe3grGfQJp-iujsG8aRuSCzmIApYiiVFE5Pkpt-EAjit4uPkXyJR+NaFE1XBo3CN8qlokSZtLgiAyLiTIBCDIewPgkQEqUliT84CTTfPY2pV4nGxjkWg1AiiHQGQVpbVR7Su7yzmTBHpAD0F4SmUMkZYzuGvzKfwiYn44jfi-kXOpRsGlrI2dUZRrS1H71TqdD8R5HmQmORI053BBmOmGU+K5RZs59GJnTCERMT4-zYNgFB8wZn1Hfti9R80HQABUalCjmooBa6DN5Gx1j8AAqqrFY2QoA0FlooQhzCVGIXIarCAcNgAZm9GDRiABSAAEoxFoXC0TnhlAAeV2gGYE6B1p0D4i7ZF7khGzOlvw+oGRdXtHeCaAAwjfNwhquh9KpRHYS50-TIEUCaF+E96iFBnOogE7d1nsy2Sw7YbT9bvTBGweQfIxIMW9URb1uq34Gr+fLReaIgEuGjdi2NeLI6gn2gcNE88NZpr4RmjpV8j4bntrmnYpyqJ6rjcWvO2jA2KkiqqvkVI0loBzQbUobAVIAHUnAptAG2mkkC0R5BFlWp4G9MTUtuTMrsY79mUpnRHHeMcLpsDkmoJV06t7oGAKPVWYMhR3HJQ6SG9EFLcsbpQlC9K6CMunCyombKqFmz9XQqWEAEYIzhjY5srYwaXoxv+h0rY4YRJzvgNGV7Dk-Ag10jIQGwMY0qRkOG9ygUnmQxzTD0xgUIY3Dh2D18NyUPRa8YjGN60bmHoeugLRuEYDYLtdB3aVKtrrNvAM080SHh7XAftwDOPtuRGiJtzLMgiZHagKBrgBBFjhS0IAA) I built recently. When I select the **Extended time rage** checkbox, more data points will show and the X axis will adjust accordingly.
When I clear the checkbox the additional data points will disappear (OK) but the X axis will not go back to the previous state (bug?).

Oddly enough if I change the time unit back and forth (for example monthly -> weekly -> monthly) then the X axis will eventually redraw correctly.

Why does this happen an how could I work-around the issue?
Also note that Y axis seem to update fine every time the checkbox toggles.

Answer (score 1):

Chart renders with expected x-axis (when clicking checkbox) if *xscale* "domain" is changed from

```
"domain": {
    "signal": "timeSequence(tbin_delivered.unit, tbin_delivered.start, tbin_delivered.stop)"
  }
```

to

```
 "domain": {"data": "deliveries", "field": "unit0", "sort": true}
```

Note: An issue with this workaround is that only time units with data are shown in the x-axis. For example, selecting time unit "daily" in the dropdown shows chart with no gaps for Saturday and Sunday when there were no deliveries.

Vega docs for *ordinal* scale and *sort* parameter:

- https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/scales/#ordinal
- https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/scales/#sort

[View chart in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-CHyb3VTAMOpcnl8gVQ6pQE26fQQXQZbTi8SSpHomVwOWwpUSEMN7bQlttkCVMmlGtWGyYLt2miTZQzeKQv0BoMLxSN7TL1t2dfaxRb0YmPdyA9TY8QjlFqQlonoP0jriPIzg0ES7YgZ2pb1EBcAgXAsg5uBwrZMobC8jIEpSugsDTlWbB9CAv7-r8lTBlArzwTBMhAvajr1AA5OR0BUYx2gANS6BWVZusW-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-yAjg1YPerBsO67xu6yAWmVoHLR+oqIYPoMfoK50sgquIoudH6SAhlNicu8tUsgMIbARB7XsUD7fwAkCgd4sHdAO3HeBBwsCDmvLJOp7nL759nPc7onaFCrLBdu92kVmr7NcB269f2x3YiKEtneK3y4f1FHOmXSnSt54C2q20H+8bqH8u9wfmDO4WN8yKx3QqkZ6B9PfInj+gehQQUoJkL8jjOGyYIoRwiRDQO4Sg7gBAFAPgdUoNI7RsGQBEPk+lzpE22CTVcu96gLzvhCJEcC4AkQEgBekr9qbPXQG8cQ+o7BlUiL8Hwfg5ayEQTUDQoBUGExVsoUmMhsG5AvhuZ2aIUgAjQIQmQ5IKaoEIfjQSa45KvxxreVckt6xXjLuZBBSCNB0nsDUNQoC74wBUDgZosYDwhEwHhNW8goDULOhUUE6UxZnT9PQ3+QdcZcnkm-L28FYz6BNP8V0dg3jMNCQWeRpCWKUVlJfJ8FCi4Ni0bGNhyDUCcIdAZZW1teFYK7krROSS0SeK2lwRAZFIZkAhBkPYHxiEE0URRKiU03zqPqKknW6TdEoJyWgnhmDPhFMpjuLsZSf4VLwrEmpdSGnERiWRJR8TEIfiPHEb87RKEgG6SbHR7D+nVEGfk4Z-DRmHXWdMTZkJJkMPXjM6pjpalPgWUWbOfRSYMwhCTQ+H82DYEQfMVZ9QX4gv4QtB0AAVHZQp5qKEWuvXwPS9ZwAAKoGxWNkKANAFaKGhpgM2lt0H7UoBrBGwAMzenBoxAApAACUYi0JGxEZDnhlAAeT2gGYE6ANp0D4q7H57l6jdDMHLch6AMjkPaO8E0ABhS+bhZVdAqcik20tVWLL9MgRQJpH7vxAIUGc-CATtyyZzXJVtiakzRPBSo8g+R0UhnyIiFrJUgDBVREZa90ALzRP-Fw7qQXPxlZHUEB0DhojnlrENZDwWr1TmMugicHbRp2A871Uqw0CPPoPS+Ijzli0zU8LW6qI5xKohM85vqy2Yg1ZHHiMc0TxDkmoXldaUUgGACPA24MhR3ARQ6aG9EFJkpDgjIUGK6BYunLikm+LCURGJTwxC466AQCRkjBGKjmytnBqOrGu6HStgRg4nO+AMZjvaaWM9iSMgHpPVjEpGQEYTE-Dcx9XN30bJPHejcX7r1CO1JOgFrxANYxPtqYeMsDYtEWd4Nge116lDYCpPkVI-GbwDL2Vl6JUMqQAOpOCDaATDNI0BRoVCEHFmQMN1jAZQVwAgizvJaEAA)

[image]

Comment: Indeed - that seems to fix the issue! I can now add a slider to control the number of days!

Comment: I used vega.github.io/vega/examples/time-units as the starting point of my chart. That example defines the domain using a signal (just like mine) but works correctly when the domain definition is changed to use data/field as per your advice. I wonder why it was done like that?

Comment: Well - actually your solution is incorrect. If you look on the X axis on your screenshot you will notice that 2022 is now to the left of 2021. Which probably also answers my question about why a signal is used to define the domain. Well... we have learned something new :)

Comment: Edited answer adding sort parameter to scale and note for issue:
 "domain": {"data": "deliveries", "field": "unit0", "sort": true}

Note: An issue with this workaround is that only time units with data are shown in the x-axis. For example, selecting time unit "daily" in the dropdown shows chart with no gaps for Saturday and Sunday when there were no deliveries.

Comment: I did think about sorting but then realised that I would hit the problem with missing days (which could also be worked around with a data transform but it is a complication)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like signal `tbin_delivered` is not updated when the time range shrinks. This is an [edited chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-CHyb3VTAMOpcnl8gVQ6pQE26fQQXQZbTi8SSpHomVwOWwpUSEMN7bQlttkCVMmlGtWGyYLt2miTZQzeKQv0BoMLxSN7TL1t2dfaxRb0YmPdyA9TY8QjlFqQlonoP0jriPIzg0ES7YgZ2pb1EBcAgXAsg5uBwqKKCZCpDIEpSugsDTlWbB9CAv7-r8lTBlArzwTBMhAvajr1AA5OR0BUYx2gANS6BWVZusW-IwegSyYSAdEOr8jEjDu2jEGwnQMD8N49iaiFDto7FceWjK8cRfr0SgeKkfU24UpmnT1FguD4EQtCTNQdCMDMCKKJU2rwZglCVAgBBIEkAgHAcOw+QIcCuAALEgUA7FATAAGxhWFcA7AAnO4UBwAIriyAAHFAqXJQcrhIKEBBofYBBwLF9oCIGAhhQI2XJfIADMKUJbFOyHLIyXJVFZipTsTCyENUVwM1BAmR5UAQMQnwQsgSLpFkZEzXYITej0cgyjQpCFLy6D0SJi57fUh3EWipSghAZjzWg+IgJk2TGfGjoGiA-Q4JCgEDPBoFCtoAD8OZlNoqDjOJQoABR7IcUjaAFACU2gADzgy2CCUMdiG6fxXYHdtu00Ao8xeulxkvnYl3iNdt2GQ9y3PZ0r12B9X0uujlDyG8u2qQAhAAvGcDCdOZ-GPYKKGivKIB5DK+1bdz2zY7R5KYDioAYli5lCZLqvETImuvMS3LiAA+lzO1K7yMQhlL7h2FLBw-n+9NPegSBkP8fAMTI-yAjg1Z3aJqv2y7hvayAWmVoHLR+oqIYPoMfqy50sgquIwudH6SAhpNifO0tbsgMIbARB7XsUD7fwAkCgd4sHdD23HeBBwsCDmjLROp7nL759nPc7on2SKEKUsF67vzQr2dh+7Xbr13bHdiCPfIp-tGu+Fr9RRzpv6d3L5OD4C2oggPdCJ6HMu98fmBO4W98G5R3QqkZ6B9KxyztAz6B6FBBTob8Rwzg2TBFCOESIaB3CUHcAIAox99qlBpHaNgyAIh8nDsSFCawACONIwRwEhpgE25sCZW0oFLOGRCIgkMVntSg0IR6UOIRbHmsh6HxBwAjc6Ls8b0g-iJcW9Q3jiH1HYNCkRfg+D8NLWQKCagaFAPpU6pDlDExkGvQ+58b5OzRCkAEaBEHlH5O8EoZRcaCTXHJfhx1byrkEegBsZdzLINQRoOk9gahqAgQbGAKgcDNFjAeEImA8LWy2lAYRys1ygnSiLbGfpxEYSDidLk8kRJe3grGfQJp-iujsG8aRuSCzmIApYiiVFE5Pkpt-EAjit4uPkXyJR+NaFE1XBo3CN8qlokSZtLgiAyLiTIBCDIewPgkQEqUliT84CTTfPY2pV4nGxjkWg1AiiHQGQVpbVR7Su7yzmTBHpAD0F4SmUMkZYzuGvzKfwiYn44jfi-kXOpRsGlrI2dUZRrS1H71TqdD8R5HmQmORI053BBmOmGU+K5RZs59GJnTCERMT4-zYNgFB8wZn1Hfti9R80HQABUalCjmooBa6DN5Gx1j8AAqqrFY2QoA0FlooQhzCVGIXIarCAcNgAZm9GDRiABSAAEoxFoXC0TnhlAAeV2gGYE6B1p0D4i7ZF7khGzOlvw+oGRdXtHeCaAAwjfNwhquh9KpRHYS50-TIEUCaF+E96iFBnOogE7d1nsy2Sw7YbT9bvTBGweQfIxIMW9URb1uq34Gr+fLReaIgEuGjdi2NeLI6gn2gcNE88NZpr4RmjpV8j4bntrmnYpyqJ6rjcWvO2jA2KkiqqvkVI0loBzQbUobAVIAHUnAptAG2mkkC0R5BFlWp4G9MTUtuTMrsY79mUpnRHHeMcLpsDkmoJV06t7oGAKPVWYMhR3HJQ6SG9EFLcsbpQlC9K6CMunCyombKqFmz9XQqWEAEYIzhoxN9NCdlcoYZgRix6OW0OA9UEeLRuEYDYLtdB3aVKtrrNvAM080SHh7XAftwDUPtuRGiJtzLMgEZHagKBrgBBFjhS0IAA); the only difference is in the tooltip (which will now show the value of `tbin_delivered.start`).

I wonder if this behavior is correct? `tbin_delivered` is calculated in the `deliveries` data stream, which is derived from stream `fruit`, which depends on the `extendedtime` signal, which does change.

Posting it as an answer because the link won't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be the values of signal *tbin_delivered.start* and *tbin_delivered.stop* are not updated when dataset *deliveries* values are changed.

The workaround in this solution is to use Vega transform *[extent](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/extent/)* to obtain minimun and maximum values of the dataset after data have changed. The function *timeSequence* in *xscale* will then show the updated domain correctly.

Added Vega transform:

```
   {
      "type": "extent",
      "field": "unit0",
      "signal": "signal_delivered_extent"
    }
```

Vega scale:

```
"scales": [
{
  "name": "xscale",
  "type": "band",
  "range": "width",
  "padding": 0.05,
  "round": true,
  "domain": {
    "signal": "timeSequence(tbin_delivered.unit, signal_delivered_extent[0], signal_delivered_extent[1] + 1)"
  }
```

Note that Vega expression function *[timeSequence](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#timeSequence)*: "Returns an array of Date instances from start (inclusive) to stop *(exclusive)*...". For the rendered x-axis domain to include the maximum value, the argument for *stop* in *timeSequence* function has to be higher than the maximum value in *signal_delivered_extent*.

[View in Vega online editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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-CHyb3VTAMOpcnl8gVQ6pQE26fQQXQZbTi8SSpHomVwOWwpUSEMN7bQlttkCVMmlGtWGyYLt2miTZQzeKQv0BoMLxSN7TL1t2dfaxRb0YmPdyA9TY8QjlFqQlonoP0jriPIzg0ES7YgZ2pb1EBcAgXAsg5uBwqKKCZCpDIEpSugsDTlWbB9CAv7-r8lTBlArzwTBMhAvajr1AA5OR0BUYx2gANS6BWVZusW-IwegSyYSAdEOr8jEjDu2jEGwnQMD8N49iaiFDto7FceWjK8cRfr0SgeKkfU24UpmnT1FguD4EQtCTNQdCMDMCKKJU2rwZglCVAgBBIEkAgHAcOw+QIcCuAALEgUA7FATAAGxhWFcA7AAnO4UBwAIriyAAHFAqXJQcrhIKEBBofYBBwLF9oCIGAhhQI2XJfIADMKUJbFOyHLIyXJVFZipTsTCyENUVwM1BAmR5UAQMQnwQsgSLpFkZEzXYITej0cgyjQpCFLy6D0SJi57fUh3EWipSghAZjzWg+IgJk2TGfGjoGiA-Q4JCgEDPBoFCtoAD8OZlNoqDjOJQoABR7IcUjaAFACU2gADzgy2CCUMdiG6fxXYHdtu00Ao8xeulxkvnYl3iNdt2GQ9y3PZ0r12B9X0uujlDyG8u2qQAhAAvGcDCdOZ-GPYKKGivKIB5DK+1bdz2zY7R5KYDioAYli5lCZLqvETImuvMS3LiAA+lzO1K7yMQhlL7h2FLBw-n+9NPegSBkP8fAMTI-yAjg1Z3aJqv2y7hvayAWmVoHLR+oqIYPoMfqy50sgquIwudH6SAhpNifO0tbsgMIbARB7XsUD7fwAkCgd4sHdD23HeBBwsCDmjLROp7nL759nPc7on2SKEKUsF67vzQr2dh+7Xbr13bHdiCPfIp-tGu+Fr9RRzpv6d3L5OD4C2oggPdCJ6HMu98fmBO4WLvi7BP0nzIa-1IvBub0b6Dh+bBNW6bOCJ9Y6xwNpRboKojLoD6KxZY7QGboD0FBAo6FfiOGcGyYIoRwiRDQO4Sg7gBAFGPvtUoNI7RsGQBEPk4diQoTWAARxpGCOAkNMAmz-orPalApZw1-hbHmshAHP0wLidwnIbxf06Jwy2e1hHAVEQcdknF4YI3Oi7PG9JYEiUfugN44h9R2DQpEX4Pg-DS1kJQmoGhQD6VOv-ZQxNX5d3lnnG+Ts0QpABGgMh5R+TvBKGUXGgk1xyW0cdW8q5dEgAbGXcyFCqEaDpPYGoahcEGxgCoHAzRYwHhCJgPC1stpQH0crNcoJ0oi2xn6YxGEg4nS5PJESXt4Kxn0Caf4ro7BvHMZ0gswSAKhIolRROT5KYIJiVeOJsYrHUNQLYh0BkFayKJquN+uEb5jLRLUzaXBEBkXEmQCEGQ9gfBIgJQZLFwFwEmm+aJsSt4JOsXyOx+MuGrM+C4w+dAuzbNQTQvClzDnHNOeoqBQztETE-HEb88Ci4PKNk8uZCzqj2PeU4-eqdTofiPDCyEfyTEAu4Acx0RynygqLNnPoxM6YQiJifRBbBsCUPmNc+oMC2Wv3mg6AAKhMoUc1FALRoVIuhPwACqqsVjZCgDQWWig2EcIEVbHhqsIBw2ABmb0YNGIAFIAASjEWhqLROeGUAB5XaAZgToHWnQPiLs6XuXqN0Mw0ttH1AyB69o7wTQAGEb5uB9V0XZoqdYhvOn6ZAigTSQInvUQoM5X4AnbvM9mSzlWOLqGieClR5B8jEgxNNRE00eugd6zF8tF5onQS4UtbLy2csjqCfaBw0Tzw1g2rRTb1lXyPhue27adgAqop6itva3Ebg8QqEIsrMh8ipE0tAbaDalDYCpAA6k4OtoBF00jwWiPIIsR1PA3pib+ELrm-OcQfUtYbI48RjhdNgck1A2rPVvdAwBR6qzBkKO4QqHSQ3ogpVVjc4ZCklXQaV045VEwVewiIMjBFgbVgjBGcMInNlbGDEDGMsMOlbHDEpOd8Bo1A7c0sxHNkZFw4RjGoyMhwyhbik8dGOYsemHi6jG52MUevhuCDTLXh8YxpO7Uw8f10BaOojAbBdo0LXSpBddZt4BmnmiQ8664BbowSppdyI0SKkiva-T+7UD4NcAIIslKWhAA)

[image]

Comment: Opened issue at: https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/3400

Comment: Thank you! - I did use this work-around and it does what I wanted.

Comment: The issue with Vega expression function timeSequence is fixed in version 5.22.0 so work around is no longer needed.

Comment: Indeed - it is fixed! Thanks for filing a bug report.